# How to efficiently delete word, colon and a comma in VIM

Tags: vim, ide, editor, vi

I often have the piece of code like this:

```
it "should do something", :focus do
  ...
end
```

When I want to delete `, :focus` I usually do

1. Go to line 1: `1G`
2. Go to the colon: `f:`
3. Delete colon (using around word, so I can repeat it): `daw`
4. Delete `focus` (just repeat previous): `.`.
5. Delete comma (move left and replace it with space): `hr<SPACE>`.

Is there any way steps 3-5 can be achieved more efficiently?

Comment: Not directly your question, but a shortcut for step 1 : `gg`, ie. press the same key twice instead of pressing two different keys...

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks for that. I was using f to highlight that the code isn't going to be on the first line. It just is here, in the question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can go:

1. `1G` to go to first line
2. `f,` to go to the comma
3. `dE` to delete till the next end of WORD (WORD in capital letters is any sequence of characters that is not space).

Comment: `dE`works amazingly well here. Even better then @rejj suggested. But I don't really understand why exactly `E` jumps over the comma, colon and a word. Would appreciate if you could explain that. Also what is opposite to `E` (move in opposite direction)?

Comment: `E` and `B` go to end (forwards) and beginning (backwards) of a WORD. `gE` and `W` go to the end of previous WORD and beginning of next WORD. `:help E`, `:help B`, `:help gE`, `:help W` will tell you! Note that there are exactly the same commands without the capital letter (`w`, `b`, `ge` and `e`) for which the definition of what a word is is different (punctuation characters are not part of words : `:help word` and `:help WORD`).

Answer (score 4):

With your cursor on the `,` you could do <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>.

or <kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>

Comment: Ohh, so simple :)!! For some reason I rarely think of comma and colon being words :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With the cursor or the colon you can do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. The <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> part will delete backwards up to and including the comma. Then <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> will delete up to the next whitespace character. The nice thing about this is that if there is no preceding comma this will still do the same thing. So with the code

```
if :focus, "should do something" do
```

If the cursor is on the colon this macro will delete just the `:focus,` part, although it will leave two spaces behind.

Comment: Nice! Similar to the suggestion by @Benoit though.

Comment: I should refresh more frequently :P

Answer (score 0):

You'd better show where your cursor is, but assuming it's after "end", I'd do this:

```
?",<CR>ldt<space>.
```

Comment: I showed where the cursor is. It is on the colon. See the step 2 in the question. The search is a very unprecise movement and breaks my flow. What is `ldt<space>` doing?

Comment: I see what `ldt<space>` is. Didn't catch it at first. With `ldt<space>` you then still need to move back and delete comma. It is similar to what I was doing in the question.